# how to install php7 mongodb driver on xampp on ubuntu

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, php-7, php-mongodb

I want to know, how to install monngodb driver for php7 in xampp on ubuntu.

I have already download driver mongodb-1.1.6.tgz. but do't know how to install.

Comment: Read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The new PHP MongoDB driver can be found in PECL.

To install, just:

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

pecl install mongodb

echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

Ultimately, this extension is not intended to be used alone. Users should considering using this driver alongside one or more userland PHP libraries, such as [mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library).

Comment: aftre 2nd step running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed